# Not get info of coingecko API

Tags: php, coingecko

I´m forking this repo https://github.com/FundacionPesetacoin/Pesetacoin_WooCommerce-Plugin and working fine. But when change the API for catch the price in other Site, not update

I try some differents links of API and make same.
Original code get info of his private API, and I want use other public API.

With original code, API show this info:

```
{"status" : "success" , "message" : "null", "ptc_btc" : "0.00000083", "btc_usd" : "5070.29", "btc_eur" : "4505.46", "supply" : "138188628.56442260", "ptc_eur" : "0.00373953", "ptc_usd" : "0.00420834" , "date" : "2019-04-13 10:20:07"}
```

and get "ptc_eur" of API for shows in shoppping cart.
Now I want use the new API of other site https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=reecore&vs_currencies=eur than shows this info:

```
{"reecore":{"eur":0.0046564}}
```

I want use only the "eur" data , same the original code use the "ptc_eur" but dont work.
Sorry for my english.

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
        //precio en PesetaCoins
global $woocommerce;
$euros= $woocommerce->cart->total;  
    $xaxa= "http://nodos.pesetacoin.info/api/api.php";
    $data = file_get_contents($xaxa);
$pesetas = json_decode($data, true);
    $valor_ptc= $pesetas['ptc_eur'];
        $ptc= $euros/$valor_ptc;
        $ptc= round($ptc, 2);
//precio en PesetaCoins

    $pagos= array();

        $metodo= $order->get_payment_method();

                        $i = -1;
                        foreach ( $this->account_details as $account ) {
                                $i++;
                            $pagos[$i]=     
                                $pagos[$i]= esc_attr( wp_unslash( $account['hash_name'] ) );
                        }

$cont= rand(0, $i);

        if($metodo == "ptc") {
        $description= "<span style='font-size:14px'>Para completar el pedido, debe enviar la cantidad <b>".$ptc."</b> de Pesetacoin a la siguiente dirección: <b>";
        $description.= $pagos[$cont];
        $description.="</b><br>Una vez se reciba la transacción se enviará el pedido.</span>";
        echo wpautop(wptexturize($description));


        }


    }
```

NEW CODE:

```
        //precio en ReecoreCoins
global $woocommerce;
$euros= $woocommerce->cart->total;  
    $xaxa= "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=reecore&vs_currencies=eur";
    $data = file_get_contents($xaxa);
$pesetas = json_decode($data, true);
    $valor_reex= $pesetas['eur'];
        $reex= $euros/$valor_reex;
        $reex= round($reex, 2);
//precio en ReecoreCoins

    $pagos= array();

        $metodo= $order->get_payment_method();

                        $i = -1;
                        foreach ( $this->account_details as $account ) {
                                $i++;
                            $pagos[$i]=     
                                $pagos[$i]= esc_attr( wp_unslash( $account['hash_name'] ) );
                        }

$cont= rand(0, $i);

        if($metodo == "reex") {
        $description= "<span style='font-size:14px'>Para completar el pedido, debe enviar la cantidad <b>".$reex."</b> de Reecorecoin a la siguiente dirección: <b>";
        $description.= $pagos[$cont];
        $description.="</b><br>Una vez se reciba la transacción se enviará el pedido.</span>";
        echo wpautop(wptexturize($description));


        }


    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what your actual question is. You need to edit the question and explain a bit better what it is you're asking/having issues with. It's currently very unclear.

Comment: Edited , sorry for not good explain.Is my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new API returns a nested JSON object, where you need two steps to access the desired value:

```
$valor_reex= $pesetas['reecore']['eur'];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the now Coingecko API return a nested JSON which is simply a JSON file with a fairly big portion of its values being other JSON objects.

Compared with **Simple** JSON, **Nested** JSON provides **higher clarity** in that it decouples objects into different layers, making it easier to maintain.

Using Phrase, keys will be stored by separating levels with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use ready library for this. Like this one https://github.com/npabisz/coingecko-api.

Install via composer:

```bash
composer require npabisz/coingecko-api
```

And then get your `reecore` price by:

```php
$client = new \CoinGecko\Client();
        
$data = $client->Simple->Price->get([
    'ids' => 'reecore',
    'vs_currencies' => 'eur',
]);

$reecorePrice = $data['reecore']['eur'] ?? null;
```